# Java - Scanner NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have checked several similar questions and, when I employed the answer that was frequently suggested, a condition that should have worked was not met.

With this code,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

// ...various code here...

public void printMenu()
{
    while (true)
    {
        System.out.println("\nPlease make a selection:\n"
                + "1) Access account\n"
                + "2) Open a new Account\n"
                + "3) Exit");

        String selection = console.nextLine();

        if (selection.equals("1")) enterPin();
        else if (selection.equals("2")) newOrReturning();
        else if (selection.equals("3"))
        {
            System.out.println("Thank you for using the BSU Banking App");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else System.out.println("Invalid entry");
    }
}
```

I am getting the error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at Menu.printMenu(Menu.java:56)
    at Menu.runMenu(Menu.java:31)
    at Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

It was suggested that `while(console.hasNextLine())` be used prior to `console.nextLine()`, but when I employed that,

```
public void printMenu()
{
    while (console.hasNextLine())
    {
        System.out.println("\nPlease make a selection:\n"
                + "1) Access account\n"
                + "2) Open a new Account\n"
                + "3) Exit");

        String selection = console.nextLine();

        if (selection.equals("1")) enterPin();
        else if (selection.equals("2")) newOrReturning();
        else if (selection.equals("3"))
        {
            System.out.println("Thank you for using the BSU Banking App");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else System.out.println("Invalid entry");
    }
}
```

Now it doesn't even execute the code, implying that there is no nextLine. Any suggestions? I apologize if there's information I missed - if there is I will edit promptly.

**Edit:** explained my problem incorrectly.

Comment: Instead of asking us to solve this for you, you should use a debugger.  Set a breakpoint, single step the code to see what is happening, examine the values / objects in the variables that the program is using .....

Comment: please try boolean trueOrFalse=true; and then put it in your test condition for while loop then at if(selection.equals("3"){ trueOrFalse=false;}

Comment: I apologize - I was more asking for suggestions than for someone to do all the legwork for me. I will do that, thank you.

Comment: also get your String initialization outside of while loop and prompt the user outside once and inside reprompt the user if he/she did not met the condition

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
public void printMenu()
{      boolean trueOrFalse=true;

        System.out.println("\nPlease make a selection:\n"
                + "1) Access account\n"
                + "2) Open a new Account\n"
                + "3) Exit");

        String selection = console.nextLine();

    while (trueOrFalse)
    {


        if (selection.equals("1")) 
        {
          enterPin(); 
          trueOrFalse=false;
        }
        else if (selection.equals("2")) 
        {
          newOrReturning(); 
          trueOrFalse=false;
        }
        else if (selection.equals("3"))
        {
            System.out.println("Thank you for using the BSU Banking App");
            trueOrFalse=false;
        }
        else 
         {   
             System.out.println("Invalid entry");
             System.out.println("\nPlease make a selection:\n"
                + "1) Access account\n"
                + "2) Open a new Account\n"
                + "3) Exit");

             selection = console.nextLine();
        }
    }
     System.exit(0);
}
```